# Unable to import to Excel using OPENROWSET in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to copy an Excel template to another folder to be able to import the data. The followings are two SQL statements that I'm using:

Statement1:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\export_templates\myExport.xlsx C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\tmp\myExport130301172218.xls'
```

Statement2:

```
insert into 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    , 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\tmp\myExport130301172218.xls;'
    , 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')  
SELECT * FROM vw_shrub
```

If I execute the above SQL Statements separately, they work fine. But if I execute them together, it raises the following error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
>   
> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   
> Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

The problem is I want to pass them both from my application as single a request. Hence, I have to execute them together. I found that i can execute them together in Management Studio, if I add GO between them. But I cannot use GO when I pass the request from my application.

Comment: Why are the paths in the copy different from the path in OPENROWSET

Comment: I'm sorry Speot. That was a mistake when I was writing the sample in my question. but the question is standing still. I updated the question. thank you.

Comment: Why not create a stored procedure and call the procedure instead from your application

Comment: Hi Raymund, I'm not sure if I get your point, but This is actually what I'm doing. I am running the two parts of the above code as a single stored procedure.

Comment: It's [generally considered bad practice](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/11/13/why-we-recommend-against-xp-cmdshell/) to use `xp_cmdshell`, especially in an application. Personally, I wouldn't do *any* of this in SQL Server.  You have to account for the fact that the database server and the application server are often not going to be the same computer.  I would fetch the data and build it from within the application itself.  There are [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120320/writing-datareader-rows-to-excel-file) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be make this two lines into two different steps in a SQL Server Agent job and execute it with a single instruction:

```
sp_start_job nameOfYourJob
```

The two steps of the job act like there was a GO in between.

Comment: Good point Zelloss. But my question is why SQL Server behaves differently when you run the two statements together. Is there any logical explanation for that behavior? When it works with GO statement, it means that everything is all right and there is no Permission issue and the syntax is correct too. But why it must be run in two different statements?

Comment: My guess is that it hasn't time to end the copy, because its an asynchronous instruction and the insert find the excel locked or still copying, just like if you try to insert in an excel that you keep opened. Perhaps this could be tested making an `exec xp_cmdshell 'dir' ` on the same directory, between the copy and the insert.

Comment: That's probably the right answer. But I was wondering if this is the case, at least the empty file should be copied at the end. Don't you think?

Comment: Mhhh, you're right. I can't think of another test to further know whats happening. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a GO after the exec statement?

Does your account connected to SQL Server have read/write access to the SQL Temp directory?  My understanding is that SQL will copy the xls file to it's temp directory and if your user doesn't have admin rights or windows read/write rights to the temp directory the connection will fail.

Comment: It is connected to the sql server.  As I mentioned, if I use Go in mng studio it works. But I cannot use it in t-sql in my code

Comment: You may be misunderstanding.  If you connect to SQL Server with user account BlahBlah, does BlahBlah have read/write access to the SQL Server temp directory (not sure what the path is but something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft\SQL Server\10.0\temp)?

Comment: The user account has the read/wrtie access. As you can see in the above explanation, if I run the statement1 and statement2 with a GO in between, it runs perfectly. But If I remove the GO line, It doesn't work. to me, it means that there is no permission issue as both scenarios are using the same username

Comment: The GO statement between them executes the batch.  It runs the rename statement and then it will load the data.  Otherwise it attempts to do that in one step instead of the two it needs.  Are there issues with having the one query have the xp_cmdshell... GO  Insert Into... GO?

Comment: I understand that. But the question is how can I run both statement at the same time? The issue with using Go is that it is OK when I'm using it in the SQL Server Management Studio, but I cannot use it in a T-SQL in my code.

Comment: What is executing the T-SQL?  Can you use that code to execute it or can you put it in a stored procedure and have your code call the stored procedure?